# Python access columns from sql without using number when reading

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am working with pyodbc to pull data and process the rows I retrieve like so

```
   data=cursoor(fetchall())
   userlist=list(data)
   
for user in userlist
    if user[3]
```

Works and all but I was wondering how to do the same but have the column names instead of
[3] example row["AccountName"] or even better user.AccountName. This is a simple script so I don't want to over-engineer but would like it to be more readable.

Comment: Perhaps read the data into a DataFrame with labelled columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [the wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#access-values-by-name), pyodbc already supports what you describe:

```py
cursor.execute("select album_id, photo_id from photos where user_id=1")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row.album_id, row.photo_id)
print(row[0], row[1])  # same as above, but less readable
```

Comment: Right, I would like to avoid using row[0] as its 0 is not descriptive.

Comment: Exactly. Look at the second-last line, where it shows that you can use `row.column_name` instead.

Comment: thanks. Guess I stopped looking when I saw the last line